# how to get the current URLs opened in Chrome, from my app?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-mountain-lion, reverse-engineering

Long story short: I have to show statics, in my OSX app, about the opened websites in Chrome. So, I need to get a list of the opened websites.

At the beginning I thought in writing a Google Chrome Extension. But found "rescuetime". They already achieve what I want (and much more). Any ideas how they get the URLs opened in Chrome, they even block them!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [looking at the source](http://www.labnol.org/software/view-source-of-chrome-extension/21284/)?